# How to undo CTRL+L in Bash in a GUIless system?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I mistakenly hitted <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd> and hiddened output from my previous viewport of the terminal window (Putty window in that case).

Of course I can scroll up with the mouse and see the Bash output but that does not bring last portion of the output to its previous place (lesser part of the window).

How to revert or "undo" <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd> in Bash non terminal-emulator CLUIs (CetnOS 12.x.x server, in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. When you pressed <kbd>CTRL-L</kbd>, `bash` didn't delete anything, it just sent an escape (`clear` = `\e[H\e[2J`) to `putty` to order it to clear the screen.

While scouring putty's memory with a *windows* debugger and hoping that those precious bits weren't already overwritten may be possible, that task is quite involved and completely offtopic here.